# kubectl -- create -h works but kubectl create -h doesn't

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Running 'minikube' on `windows 10`, why `minikube kubectl create -h` doesn' work but `minikube kubectl -- create -h` does (w.r.t. showing help for `create`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way minikube works:

Minikube has a subcommand `kubectl` that will exectute the `kubectl` bundled with minikube (because you can also have one installed outside of minikube, on your plain system).

Minikube has to know the exact command to pass to its `kubectl`, thus minikube splits the command with `--`.

It's used to differentiate minikube arguments and kubectl's.