# Unknown image flag when creating deployment using Minikube kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am getting `unknown image flag` when creating a deployment using `minikube` on `windows 10` `cmd`. Why?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube kubectl create deployment nginxdepl --image=nginx
Error: unknown flag: --image
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using [kubectl bundled with minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/) the command is little different.

From the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/), your command should be:

```
minikube kubectl -- create deployment nginxdepl --image=nginx
```

The difference is the `--` right after `kubectl`

Comment: thanks. More information here (explains why) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134922/kubectl-create-h-works-but-kubectl-create-h-doesnt/68141042#68141042

Answer (score 2):

there problem is your command. you are mixing kubectl and minikube.

minikube is for managing your one-node local dev cluster.
kubectl is used for interacting with your cluster.

you should be using the following command:

```
kubectl create deployment nginxdepl --image nginx
```